# Is possible on Android control speed of MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Is possible on Android control speed of MediaPlayer ? I need to implement to multiply or divide speed with two ( on user click on x2 and /2 buttons, very large files over 100MB). How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The Android MediaPlayer doesn't provide direct access to the playback rate. However, SoundPool does. Try the setRate(int streamID, float rate)  function in it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Answer (score 0):

[setPlaybackParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setPlaybackParams(android.media.PlaybackParams)) for API 23+ should make it possible now.